Docker wget returning a 404 error for a Github repo
Im attempting to download the following GitHub repo
https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module
and getting a 404 error when docker executes the wget command. The repo is a customized version of nginx rtmp module.
Here are the problematic lines :
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.23.1
ARG NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION=1.2.2

# Download and decompress customized RTMP module. 
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/build/nginx-rtmp-module && \
    cd /tmp/build/nginx-rtmp-module && \
    wget -O nginx-rtmp-module-${NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION}.tar.gz https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module/archive/v${NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf nginx-rtmp-module-${NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    cd nginx-rtmp-module-${NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION}

I replaced the following lines with the above since I required a customized version of the Nginx rtmp module. The one below has no issues.
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/build/nginx && \
cd /tmp/build/nginx && \

wget https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp- 
module/archive/v${NGINX_RTMP_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar zxf v${NGINX_RTMP_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    rm v${NGINX_RTMP_VERSION}.tar.gz

I cant figure this one out. I used the github repo url and pasted it in the link field.From the initial look , it could be the NGINX_RTMP_MODULE_VERSION which could be wrong but I'm not sure. Kindly guide me in the right direction.
Thanking in advance.

The repo you are pulling from https://github.com/ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module does not have a v1.2.2 package, see available releases here.
Compare with your original repo's releases (arut/nginx-rtmp-module) here.
The latest available in ut0mt8/nginx-rtmp-module is v1.2.0.

Thank you Jason. I will input the about and come back with the results.
